# Selecting a part of text in JSpinner on click

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have a JSpinner with `SpinnerDateModel`. I want when users click on any part of the editor (the date, month, or year), it will automatically select them. So I wrote this:

```
JSpinner dateSpn = new JSpinner();
dateSpn.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel());
JSpinner.DateEditor editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(dateSpn, "dd-MM-yyyy");
dateSpn.setEditor(editor);
JFormattedTextField field = editor.getTextField();
field.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
        int i = field.getCaretPosition();
        if (i <= 2) {
            field.select(0, 2);
        } else if (i >= 3 && i <= 5) {
            field.select(3, 5);
        } else if (i >= 6){
            field.select(6, 10);
        }
    }
});
```

But when the first time it clicked, nothing happened. Although when I click it again, it works perfectly. Where's wrong with my code?

Comment: Does it work when you use `mouseClicked` or `mouseReleased` instead of `mousePressed`? The caret position might not be correctly updated yet when the `mousePressed` is executed.

Comment: It works! How stupid of me without trying it first. I always use `mousePressed` instead of `mouseClicked`, I thought they're same. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: By default, `JSpinner` selects the date field when you double click the mouse on it. Is that not good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`MouseAdapter#mousePressed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html#mousePressed-java.awt.event.MouseEvent-):

```
Invoked when a mouse button has been pressed on a component.
```

Which means this is executed when the mouse has only been pressed (not yet released mind you). So this is the first of the clicked / pressed / released methods to be invoked.

The issue you are having then is, that at this point in time, when `mousePressed` is invoked, your `JFormattedTextField`s caret position might not have been correctly updated yet. Hence the issue you are encountering.

The solution is to switch to `mouseClicked()` (or `mouseReleased()` as an alternative), because at that point, you can be sure that your `JFormattedTextField` has been updated correctly and the invoked method gets the correct value.